# Are there speed benefits of putting CSS attributes in alphabetical order?

Tags: css, parsing

I hope this question isn't too weird and arbitrary. When I'm viewing some CSS using Firebug, I've noticed that the CSS properties for each tag are in alphabetical order.

Is it trying to tell us something?

Apart from the obvious benefit of being able to find the property you're after more quickly, I was wondering this: Is it quicker for a browser to apply the properties if they are in alphabetical order in the original stylesheet?

For example is this...

```
body {
  background: #222;
  color: #DDD;
  font-size: 0.85em;  
}

#content {
  background: #444;
  padding: 1em;
}

p {
  border-bottom: 0.9em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

...better than this...?

```
body {
  font-size: 0.85em;
  background: #222;
  color: #DDD;  
}

#content {
  padding: 1em;
  background: #444;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  border-bottom: 0.9em;
}
```

Can this be tested effectively?

This would obviously be replicated throughout the entire stylesheet so would a browser benefit from doing things in order and, if so, would it be worth revisiting past stylesheets to reorder things?

-- edit --

Ok, a slight alteration to my question: What if the attributes are always in the same order for each tag. Background always before border always before color etc and so on (I know I've missed some!) for each and every tag. Alphabetical would aid you in keeping things in order rather than being the optimal method.

Looks like the overwhelming consensus is that it matters not, however!

Comment: I am 99.999999999% sure the list is alphabetical only for the benefit of the developer looking at it. Depending on how browsers parse style sheets, there may be an optimal order, but I can't think of a reason why that order should be *alphabetical*
 of all things

Comment: Even if there is a difference, it would probably be measured in nanoseconds.

Comment: Alphabetical order is the natural order for any language that is represented with an alphabet.  Ordering elements using the alphabet helps the developer who is maintaining and/or debugging the code.  It almost never impacts the run speed of code.

Answer (score 3):

There's definitely no speed benefit in ordering your styles alphabetically.

If you want real speed benefits, you should minify your CSS.

There are so many programs to do that, but here's one of them: [CSSTidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/). This program also has the option to put your styles in alphabetical order (if you want that for *your* benefit).

Comment: Are you talking about overall speed or parsing speed?  Parsing text is expensive, but I'm guessing most of that expense is when a token is encountered, minifying will save space, but won't reduce the complexity of the document.

Comment: @mikerobi: Although you are right that *most* of that expense Is when a token is encountered, whitespace definitely slows it down *somewhat*. Try it yourself with a regEx. Also, download speed is a big factor in perceived page load time.

Comment: I agree, but think that "somewhat" amounts to nanoseconds unless you have a huge file. I agree about download time, that it why I asked about "overal speed" or "parsing speed".

Comment: i agree.  your css order is for designers to organize for themselves.  for me i just really prefer to go position size color etc... it's just preference.  no speed difference that i have found anywhere on the internet.  and compressing the css is great... do that when you upload the final... and keep the full version for future changes... (you don't want to have to sort through a compressed css file later.) i also leave the full version somewhere on the server for anyone else that might need it in the future.  i think that you can consider this question answered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think order of statements affects speed in any way, however, the efficiency of the statements can affect performance. (Slightly tangential, I guess...)

See: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#UseEfficientCSSSelectors

Answer (score 0):

The performance benefit is for visual parsing only - FireBug will re-arrange your style attributes into alphabetical order when you inspect an element, which I find much quicker to locate a style attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug do it so that developers can search for an attribute value easily, and if you want speed benefit, write your css judiciously, which includes mainly avoiding repetition and redundancy and being DRY

Also when a page loads and CSS is parsed and layout is rendered once, next time its not done again, so stay calm, and try to make it more maintainable instead

Answer (score 0):

Writing CSS in an alphabetical order just makes one thing easy: finding your attribute. It has nothing to do with speed.

To Increase speed, you can use shorthands rather than using separate attributes. Things like `border-color`, `border-width`, `border-style` can be used in a single attribute called `border`.