# Is there a performance benefit to sorting CSS properties?

Tags: css, optimization, properties, minify

I am designing a little minifier for stylesheets, and I am curious if there is any need for me to sort the properties of each selector into a specific order that increases performance, or if it really doesn't matter?

For example, is it better for the browser if the properties are in alphabetical order, or some other specific order?

Comment: I would imagine if this matters at all it would be implementation specific.  You could easily have different "optimal" orders based on each browser.

Comment: why don't you just test if there is another loading and rendering time for a webpage with different css-sorting. If you do it, let me know what comes out. Would be interesting to know.

Comment: I asked that very question once, seemed to not affect things, though no evidence was given. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080934/are-there-speed-benefits-of-putting-css-attributes-in-alphabetical-order

Comment: Browsers parse stylesheets before rendering, so, i suspect, sorting properties inside of the rules is completely useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Order matters* in CSS. Different rules can override each other based on their order. You'll have a hell of a time debugging your CSS if the order is automatically changed. Based on that alone you shouldn't do it. Furthermore, how much benefit can it possibly bring? Does the CSS parsing noticeably slow down your page loading?

Comment: No, it's not noticeably slowing anything down...but since i was on the subject of optimization, I figured it was a worthwhile thought.